# rajawali and md2 animation files

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0, rajawali

my first question here.

i try to use rajawali engine to render some md2 animation files.
i truly new for this,and dont really know how to create my own md2 files.
so i find some md2 files over the net,but now i have a problem:

in the ragawali examples there is 2 relevant files:
1.ogro.md2 (in res/raw path)
2.ogrobase.jpg  (in res/drawable-nodpi path)

but,in the other md2 files -like from this website:(http://www.md2.sitters-electronics.nl/models.html)-i get md2 files with PCX and BMP or PNG files..

so the md2 files load as i want,but it can read the "skin" or the texture that attched.

how can i modified this files that i could use it with ragewali,which is the best way?is the md2 file defined which is the file to read the texture from it?becouse i dont know how to midified it..

many thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The MD2 file format is quite an old format. It was used for Quake 2 which was released in 1997. The preferred texture formats in those days were .pcx or .tga. 1997 is a long time ago and nowadays .jpg and .png files are used as textures. These are fully supported by the Android platform.

I suggest using Photoshop, The Gimp or XNView to convert your .pcx images into jpegs. You can use the same file name and drop them into your "drawable-nodpi" folder. Rajawali automatically strips off the path and file extension from all the textures it finds in the .md2 file. So you don't have to worry about manually editing your .md2 file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Blender 2.57 to create your MD2 files i am doing the same too. and in ogrobase.png is UV image of its texture i have performed this tutorial. this UV image details(names) are stored in the MD2 file so u need same everything to be same as it was exported. My suggestion would be using blender 2.57 there is an exporter MD2 script for it available and u can create ur own files.